# iframe content in IE11 is shows only white screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-browser

I need to display an pdf file in `iframe` tag using JavaScript

Here is my `iframe`

```
<iframe  id="iframeFile" name="iframeFile" src="" width="100%" height="100%" title="File" scrolling="auto" style="position:relative;"></iframe>

$('#iframeFile').attr('src', '');
```

> pdf is displaying in chrome and firefox. But in internet explorer it shows white blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Does it show the option to download the file when you try to open it in IE 11?

Try to check the **Adobe Shockwave** add on is installed and enabled in Internet Explorer.

If it is not available or disabled than IE can show you the blank screen and prompt you to download the PDF file to view it locally.

If it is not available in your IE add on list than you can download it from Adobe website.

[Adobe Shockwave Player](https://get.adobe.com/shockwave/)